# How to POST json data to the server? (CORS error)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, webforms, cors

**My goal**
I am doing **.aspx** file on **Microsoft Visual Studio**. What I expect is that the system will scan the QR code and then send the JSON data to the server side.
PS. I am using **XMLHttpRequest** to send the data.

**What I Get**
First I tried to pass it directly, it does not work so I check its status and readyStats, what it shows is 1(open) and 0(not initialized) (I am expecting 4(done) and 200(ok)) the responseText is null. I then inspected my browser (Google Chrome), the console shows an error **"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://website-A.aspx' from origin 'https://localhost:44371' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."**

**What I tried**
So I searched for solution on stack overflow, most of them says that I need to put in the header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*** to the server, but the problem is I do not have the control of the server but I do contacted them to change the code to try it out, end up **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*** doesn't work so I looked for alternative. I tried to use plugin such as [Moesif Origin & CORS Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc/related) but it shows **"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://website-A.aspx' from origin 'https://localhost:44371' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute."**.

**Below is my code:**

```
       function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
           ...
           
           var url = "https://Website-A.aspx";

           var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhr.withCredentials = true;
           xhr.open("POST", url);

           xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
           xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

           xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
               if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                   console.log(xhr.status);
                   console.log(xhr.responseText);
               }
           };

           //I hardcoded the data for testing
           var data = {
               "SOME_ID": "Value",
               "SOME_TYPE": "Value",
               "SOME_ID": "Value",
               "SOME_AMT": "Value",
               "SOME_AMT_CURRENCY": "Value",
               "SOME_DESC": "Value",
               ...
           };

           xhr.send(data);
       }
```

Is there anyway to solve this without changing the server side's code or bypassing the CORS?

I wish to solve this by modify the code in the same .aspx only, is it possible?

If my code ain't going to work, is there any other way to do it?

Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

cors must be allowed on server side. your code looks ok.

sorry, i can't use the comment function yet